# Mysql query check the blob column type in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, blob, where-clause

I found out that `CONVERT(object USING utf8)` is for converting blob to text, but it doesn't seem efficient in the where clause, like this:

```
Select * 
from Page 
where CONVERT(Page.page_title USING utf8) = 'AccessibleComputing'
```

Is this the only way and the correct way? because it is taking too much time. Or should I convert 'AccessibleComputing' to binary in a way and then put it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
Select * from Page where Page.page_title = 'AccessibleComputing'
```

I think after all it doesn't need any conversion.

Comment: That's because in this case, MySQL will convert the constant to match the column type. Still, you'll be doing a table scan without an index. So, if this is fast, I'm assuming you have an index on page_title.

Answer (score 0):

Do these work?

```
Select *, CAST(Page.page_title AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) AS Tmp
from Page
where Tmp = 'AccessibleComputing'
```

OR

```
Select *, CONVERT(Page.page_title USING utf8) AS Tmp
from Page
where Tmp = 'AccessibleComputing'
```

Comment: Thanks Asef, It seems I just made it complicated and it was not necessary.